# ObjectBox: Can an observable query detect changes to related entities?

Tags: kotlin, objectbox

Is there a way for an observable query to detect when a related entity changes, and notify its subscribers? The following uses a one-to-one relationship between a person and an address. I would like the person query to be notified when a person's address changes.

```
@Entity
data class Person(@Id val id: Long = 0) {
    @Backlink
    lateinit var homeAddress: ToOne<Address>
}

@Entity
data class Address(@Id var id: Long = 0) {
    lateinit var person: ToOne<Person>
}

// Build a query for the parent
val query = boxStore.boxFor<Person>.().query().build()
query.find()

// I want to be notified when the address changes
query.subscribe(...)

// Update a child object
val address = person.homeAddress.target ?: return
val newAddress = address.copy(street="...")
boxStore.boxFor<Address>.put(newAddress)
```

This updates the address box as expected, but the person query is not notified. Any way to accomplish that?

Comment: Also looking for the same solution. Please post here if you find any Thanks